# What should I consider when determining JWT expiration time?

Tags: jwt, json-web-token

Isn't it effective to never let the JWT expire so that user automatically logs in? Is there  a security problem with it?

I don't want to use session and or cookie. They are ineffective.

Comment: If you just need a session, use a session cookie and don't bother with JWT.

Comment: @pvg i dont want to use session or cookie.

Comment: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/  there are also plenty of other problems with JWT, especially if security is a concern.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvote. It is a good question. Even, i took a moment to google and learn about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, it is effective in case the token gets stolen. If you have an infinite expiration time, the intruder has access to the protected resource for the lifetime. Think of it this as your password for personal mail. It is often a good idea to change it periodically so that if someone has obtained your password without your knowledge, he won't be able to access your email again after that.
Having said that, it is not compulsory to have the expiration time.
according to [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4)

> The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on
> or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The
> processing of the "exp" claim requires that the current date/time
> MUST be before the expiration date/time listed in the "exp" claim. Implementers MAY provide for some small leeway, usually no more than
> a few minutes, to account for clock skew.  Its value MUST be a number
> containing a NumericDate value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318233/when-jwt-expires-will-the-jwt-stored-in-local-storage-be-removed-automatically